# How to trigger route and collect results using Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse

Route A is triggered by quartz2 component (according to cron schedule). When route A completes it's business logic in some cases I need to trigger route B which will read all files from given directory and sends results to another route C but it's undesirable to leave route B running all the time.

How to run route B only once when route A needs it ? Currently I am using 'controlbus:' command in route A to start route B (autoStart=false) and Route C is using 'controlbus:' again to stop Route B. Could you propose better solution for my use-case ?

Answer (score 0):

'Route A' implements pooling consumer which polls all files from given directory (as we iterate). Polling will be stopped as we receive null body (check http://camel.apache.org/file2.html sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle option)

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

List<GenericFile> result = new ArrayList<GenericFile>();    
String endpointUrl  = "file:////tmp?sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true"
PollingConsumer pConsumer = camelContext.getEndpoint(endpointUrl).createPollingConsumer();

pConsumer.start();

GenericFile<File> gFile;

do {
    Exchange ex = pConsumer.receive(SCAN_TIMEOUT);
    gFile = (GenericFile<File>) ex.getIn().getBody();
    if(gFile != null) {
        result.add(gFile);
    }
// use &sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true in file endpoint url OR set receive timeouts otherwise you will never know when folder scan has finished !!!
} while(gFile != null);

pConsumer.stop();

// other business logic 

}
```